# Rails ActiveRecord::Base.transaction not reversing when one resource fails to create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, transactions, rails-activerecord

In my Rails 7 app I have a simple service for parsing a CSV to create earnings records. Each earning is tied to an employee and an employee belongs to an employer.

Each row of the CSV has `external_ref`, which is a string for the employee. Before creating the earning, I want to first find or create an employee by the `external_ref`. Once the employee has been found or created, let's then create an earning.

In case the earning fails to create, the employee, if created, should be destroyed as well in the ActiveRecord transaction. However, the employee is not being deleted.

I have my CSV service class like this:

```
      data = CSV.read(@file_path, headers: true)
      data.each do |earning_data|
        ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
          employee_found = Employee.find_or_create_by(earning_data['external_ref'])
          Earning.create(employee: employee_found,
                         earning_date: earning_data['earning_date'],
                         amount: earning_data['amount'])
        end
      end
```

Let's say one row of the CSV has `nil` for amount, this will trigger the earning not to be created. Indeed, the earnings will not be created when I run this code. However, the employees are still being created and not being destroyed.

How should I ensure, when the earning fails to create, the employee newly created is also destroyed?

I've tried using `Employee.transaction` and `Earning.transaction` instead of `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction`. But still won't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DB methods you've used (`create` and `find_or_create_by`) simply return false when they fail. You need the `!` versions that raise an exception on failure.